# What is this plant with two different kinds of flowers?

Tags: identification

What is this plant with two different kinds of flowers? It is loved by bees and other polinators.

How come it has flowers of two colors on the same plant?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome Aleksandar M! Thanks for joining us, and contributing your pretty plant questions!  With identification questions, we have a few important [guidelines](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info), so you can get the best answers. We always need the location, so please add that to all of your questions. Pictures too, and yours are great! The more details in the title and question, the better! I invite you to visit our [help], [Ask] is a great place to start. If you need help with any of our features, leave a comment and someone will come along!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it seems much more the [Echium Vulgare (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echium_vulgare), also because the flowers change colour, and flowers are not so symmetric.

Comment: This is what I thought - vipers bugloss. I've grown it from seed in the garden before.

Answer (score 1):

Gosh this is some kind of Campanula.  Blue bells?  Baby flowers can easily slide from whites to purples to blues...whatever this plant is it is showing serious deficiency in chemistry necessary for the plant.  Have you fertilized at all?  This plant needs a bit of balanced fertilizer.  NPK...even numbers or the first number should be slightly lower than the P and K.