# What is this 2ft tall plant with narrow serrated leaves?

Tags: identification

I hope characteristic leaves and flowers are going to be sufficient for identification:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

### [image]

Edit: I just discovered that seed pods and flowers have magnificent lemony fragrance.

Comment: It does look like a member of the Lamiaceae, but I'd like to see another photo taken a little further away which shows more of the overall growth habit and the leaves please

Comment: Thanks for the new photos. Would you please add the location to your identification questions? It would only take a minute and it's really important. The comment I left you on [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39835/what-is-this-plant-with-two-different-kinds-of-flowers) explains why we ask it. You have lovely plants and following our guidelines will make things easier for everyone. If there's a reason why you don't want to add the location, please let us know. We can figure something out. Thanks!

Comment: @Bamboo Can you perhaps help? Lemony fragrance...

Answer (score 2):

Well it appears to be a mint with square stem and typical mint flower, one flower possibly two in the axil, lilac colour and narrow serrate leaf. My first unsure pick would be Marsh Skullcap [(*Scutellaria galericulata*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scutellaria_galericulata) although for this to be right there needs to be two flowers, or at least one plus the effort to produce a second, in each axil.

Comment: It looks very close, but your guess lacks scent. Bu it was very close.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Fall Obedient Plant (Physostegia virginiana).  It has the square stem and is in the mint family, but I don't recall whether it has the lemony scent you described.